# Execute function with value of current selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Even if i have selected an options it still alert a message "Please choose something."
I got this working with only one dropdown list, but i have problems when there are two or more.

(In working example variable sport is document.getElementById("sports") and only one dropdown list)

What's the issue?

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function check() {
    sport = document.getElementsByClassName("sports");
    sport_selected = sport.selectedIndex; 
    weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
    time = document.getElementById("time").value;
    if (sport_selected > 0) {
        if (isNaN(weight, time)) {
        alert("Error. This is not a number.");
        }
        else { 
        met = sport.options[sport_selected].value;
        calculations = (time * ((met * 3.5 * weight)/200));  
        result = Math.round(calculations);
        document.lastform.output.value = result + " kcal";
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Please choose something.")
    } 
});
</script> 
<div id="tabs">     
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Running</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Walking</a></li>  
</ul>                   
<div id="tabs-1">
<form name="form1">
    <select class="sports">
        <option value="">-Choose-</option>
        <option value="6">Jog/walk combination</option>
        <option value="7">Jogging, general</option>
        <option value="8">Running, 5 mph (12 min/miile)</option>
        <option value="9">Running, 5.2 mph (11.5 min/mile)</option>
        <option value="10">Running, 6 mph (10 min/mile)</option>
  </select>
</form>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<form name="form2">
    <select class="sports">
        <option value="">-Choose-</option>
        <option value="2">Walking, general</option>
        <option value="2">Walking, 1 mph</option>
  </select>
</form>
</div>
</div>  
<form name="lastform">
<label for="weight">Weight [kg]:</label><br />
<input type="text" size="3" id="weight"><br />   
<label for="time">Duration [min]:</label><br />
<input type="text" size="3" id="time">
<input type="button" value="Calc" onClick="check()"><br /><br />
<label for="kcal">You have burned:</label><br />
<input type="text" id="output">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByClassName is returning a collection but not just one item,  you need to write code to iterate the collection if you have more controls. please check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: I see. Now I understand that getElementsByClassName isn't the way.

Answer (score 0):

What about using jQuery, since you've used the TAG ?

**HTML**

```
<div id="tabs">     
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Running</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Walking</a></li>  
</ul>                   
<div id="tabs-1">
<form name="form1">
    <select class="sports">
        <option value="">-Choose-</option>
        <option value="6">Jog/walk combination</option>
        <option value="7">Jogging, general</option>
        <option value="8">Running, 5 mph (12 min/miile)</option>
        <option value="9">Running, 5.2 mph (11.5 min/mile)</option>
        <option value="10">Running, 6 mph (10 min/mile)</option>
  </select>
</form>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<form name="form2">
    <select class="sports">
        <option value="">-Choose-</option>
        <option value="2">Walking, general</option>
        <option value="2">Walking, 1 mph</option>
  </select>
</form>
</div>
</div>  
<form name="lastform">
<label for="weight">Weight [kg]:</label><br />
<input type="text" size="3" id="weight"><br />   
<label for="time">Duration [min]:</label><br />
<input type="text" size="3" id="time">
<input type="button" value="Calc" id="check"><br /><br />
<label for="kcal">You have burned:</label><br />
<input id="result" type="text" id="output">
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
$("#check").click(function() {

    var sport_selected = $(".sports option:selected").val();
    var weight = $("#weight").val();
    time = $("#time").val();
    if (parseInt(sport_selected) > 0) {
        if (isNaN(weight, time)) {
            alert("Error. This is not a number.");
        }
        else {
            var met = sport_selected
            calculations = (time * ((met * 3.5 * weight) / 200));
            result = Math.round(calculations);
            $("#result").val(result + " kcal");
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Please choose something.")
    }
});​
```

and this is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/WExxJ/1/).